# Targeting Sources With Google Analytics Experiments

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api, google-experiments

I am curious if Google Analytics Content Experiments supports targeting based on the traffic source, in particular, certain Google Adwords campaigns.

For example, I have two Adwords campaigns pointed to the same destination url but would like a Content Experiment to only run for one of these two campaigns.

Even targeting the experiment based on the referring url would be helpful but I don't see an option to do so when setting up the experiment. Does anyone know if this is possible through the set up, or if I would need to create some kind of gateway that my campaigns funnel through and then get routed to the experiment URL based on the source?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does not currently provide this function by default.

I'd try https://www.optimizely.com/ (easier) and/or patching up custom bucketing code (more difficult)